# What am I doing wrong in my Haskell library installation/usage?

Tags: haskell, neural-network, haskell-stack

I want to install and run an example program from the Haskell [neural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/neural) library.

I'm pretty new to this and am not sure on whether the issue is with my installation method, my environment or the library(ies?) itself. How do I get one of the example programs running?

I tried `stack install neural`  and got

```
Error: [S-4804]
       Stack failed to construct a build plan.

       While constructing the build plan, Stack encountered the following errors. The 'Stack configuration' refers to the set of package versions specified
       by the snapshot (after any dropped packages, or pruned GHC boot packages; if a boot package is replaced, Stack prunes all other such packages that
       depend on it) and any extra-deps:

       In the dependencies for neural-0.3.0.1:
         * pipes-zlib needed, but no version is in the Stack configuration (latest matching version is 0.4.4.2).
       needed since neural is a build target.

       Some different approaches to resolving some or all of this:

         * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\stack\global-project\stack.yaml
           (project-level configuration):

           - pipes-zlib-0.4.4.2@sha256:eabd5aa29a030ecdeade80cfeb1787adc181bcf8fd378cb7b695b2af6cb26af6,1947
```

After following the recommended action,

```
 While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the error:

       [S-7011]
       While building package neural-0.3.0.1 (scroll up to its section to
       see the error) using:
       C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_9p6GVs8J_3.10.1.0_ghc-9.6.4.exe --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ab060f89 build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
       Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

After this, I tried `cabal install neural` instead, and got

```
Failed to build neural-0.3.0.1.
Build log (
C:\cabal\logs\ghc-9.4.8\neural-0.3.0.1-41d9f5ecd7dfa38845ecaf8f9f447447e7958da2.log
):
Preprocessing library for neural-0.3.0.1..
Building library for neural-0.3.0.1..
[ 1 of 22] Compiling Data.MyPrelude   ( src\Data\MyPrelude.hs, dist\build\Data\MyPrelude.o )

src\Data\MyPrelude.hs:55:1: warning: [-Wunused-imports]
    The import of `Data.Monoid' is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from `Data.Monoid'
    To import instances alone, use: import Data.Monoid()
   |
55 | import Data.Monoid                ((<>))
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ 2 of 22] Compiling Data.FixedSize.Class ( src\Data\FixedSize\Class.hs, dist\build\Data\FixedSize\Class.o )

.........
    |
120 | vtail (Vector v) = Vector $ VS.tail v
    |                                     ^
[17 of 22] Compiling Numeric.Neural.Model ( src\Numeric\Neural\Model.hs, dist\build\Numeric\Neural\Model.o )

src\Numeric\Neural\Model.hs:139:10: error:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance (NFData (s a), NFData (t a)) => NFData (Product s t a)
        -- Defined at src\Numeric\Neural\Model.hs:139:10
      instance [safe] (Control.DeepSeq.NFData1 f,
                       Control.DeepSeq.NFData1 g, NFData a) =>
                      NFData (Product f g a)
        -- Defined in `Control.DeepSeq'
    |
139 | instance (NFData (s a), NFData (t a)) => NFData (Product s t a) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: cabal-3.10.2.1.exe: Failed to build neural-0.3.0.1 (which is requiredby exe:sqrt from neural-0.3.0.1, exe:sin from neural-0.3.0.1 and others). See
the build log above for details.
```

At this point, I assume it's an issue with the [source itself?](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/neural-0.3.0.1/reports/3)

When I try installing other related libraries (e.g, grenade) using stack, I get something like

```
 fail (backjumping, conflict set: singletons, template-haskell,
th-desugar)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: grenade, text, singletons,
template-haskell, th-desugar, base
```

Comment: I'm afraid `neural` and `grenade` are dead projects. To my knowledge the only (somewhat) viable deep learning library is still [`hasktorch`](https://github.com/hasktorch/hasktorch).

Comment: I did consider that might be the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build `neural` with Stack, but I started with a clone of the Git repository instead of trying `stack install neural` (which looks like it's broken).  So, try:

```
git clone https://github.com/brunjlar/neural.git
cd neural
stack build
```

The first time, I got a dreaded GHC panic:

```
$ stack build
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 8.0.2 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
    Prelude.chr: bad argument: 3179719811

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug

Error: [S-6374]
       While building simple Setup.hs (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
       /u/buhr/.ghcup/ghc/8.0.2/bin/ghc -rtsopts -threaded -clear-package-db
       -global-package-db -hide-all-packages -package base -main-is
       StackSetupShim.mainOverride -package Cabal-1.24.2.0 
       /scratch/buhr/haskell/stack/setup-exe-src/setup-6HauvNHV.hs 
       /scratch/buhr/haskell/stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-6HauvNHV.hs 
       -o /scratch/buhr/haskell/stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_6HauvNHV_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2
```

which seems to result from some buggy Stack behavior when switching between old and new GHC versions.  If you get this error, take a look at the directory referenced at the end of the message (in my case, `/scratch/buhr/haskell/stack/setup-exe-src`), delete any interface files in that directory (extension `.hi`), and try rebuilding.

As per @leftroundabout's comment, this might be abandonware, but it may be suitable for flower identification purposes:

```
$ stack exec iris
read 150 samples

generation  learning rate  model error  accuracy

      1000         0.0833     0.324557    0.9600
      2000         0.0714     0.293898    0.9800
      3000         0.0625     0.291766    0.9733
      4000         0.0556     0.283495    0.9867
      5000         0.0500     0.282830    0.9867
      6000         0.0455     0.281650    0.9733
      7000         0.0417     0.279772    0.9800
      8000         0.0385     0.279185    0.9867
      9000         0.0357     0.280861    0.9800
     10000         0.0333     0.278089    0.9867
     11000         0.0312     0.281700    0.9800
     12000         0.0294     0.277957    0.9867
     13000         0.0278     0.277410    0.9867
     14000         0.0263     0.277250    0.9867
     15000         0.0250     0.276689    0.9800
     16000         0.0238     0.277031    0.9867
     17000         0.0227     0.277748    0.9867
     18000         0.0217     0.277142    0.9867
     19000         0.0208     0.275976    0.9867
     20000         0.0200     0.275764    0.9867
     21000         0.0192     0.276158    0.9867

reached prediction accuracy of 0.993 after 21500 generations
```

Comment: Thank you! I did try fiddling around with the git code, but `stack build` and `stack exec` were the pieces I missed. I'm afraid my knowledge of the build pipeline is pretty sketchy - are there any simple resources for this?

Comment: Well, there's the Stack [documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/) which contains a [User's Guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/) as a separate section. Not sure how helpful that would be here, though.